# Find $F(2x)$ from $F(x) = a^x \bmod p$

Tags: encryption, keys, discrete-logarithm

Given $F(x) = a^x \bmod p$, where $a$ is a primitive root of $p$,
Is it possible to work out what $F(2x)$ or $F(3x)$, etc if you know
what $F(x)$ is but not $x$.

If you use $F(x)$ then $F(2x)$, etc as session keys for a cryptosystem would be knowing a previous key compromise future keys.

Comment: Hint: $a^{2x} = (a^x)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing [fkraiem's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63119/find-f2x-from-fx-ax-bmod-p#comment139867_63119) as an answer:

> Hint:   $$a^{2x}=(a^x)^2$$

which also holds $\bmod p$.

Comment: FWIW, when I write a hint as a comment like that, it's with the expectation that OP will expand it into a full solution and submit it themselves (a good way to get rep!). Maybe I should make that explicit...